# "call_to_action_type field in creative is required in this ad" returned while creating ads using marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

When I use adcreatives endpoint with object_story_spec parameter to create ads or using object_story_id parameter following instructions in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/mobile-app-ads/v2.3) :

I got this error message:

> {"error":{"message":"Invalid
>   parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":1487664,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Missing
>   Call To Action Type","error_user_msg":"call_to_action_type field in
>   creative is required in this ad"}}

*Anyone knows how to solve this problem?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you not setting the call_to_action field? While it's not explicitly stated in the docs (as far as I can see) the field is mentioned for all ads for mobile app install or engagement campaigns so I suggest setting it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/mobile-app-ads/v2.2#cta_definitions

Comment: I have set this field, and have also set call_to_action_type, but still got this error.

Comment: You may have found a FB platform bug then. When I suspect that I first replicate the issue on the Graph API Explorer and try to use the new debug options there to see if I can learn more. If still an error file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've posted a bug report, and they replied me that  I should set a picture larger than 1200 * 628 pixels. The previous picture I set was too small, but it returned me a missing call_to_action_type error.